# rbash can't use tab to completion path in ubuntu 20.4

Tags: bash

I created a user and set bash to rbash.
On centos7.x, users can use tab to complete the path.
It doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04, is there any additional configuration required?

i use ansible playbook to create user:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all 
  user: root
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    limit_user: "programer"
  tasks:
    - name: "clean dir"
      file:
        state: absent
        path: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin'
    - name: "create a directory if it doesn't exist"
      file:
        state: directory
        path: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin'
        mode: 0755
        group: root
        owner: root
    - name: "create symbolic link for {{ limit_user }}"
      when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
      file:
        state: link
        src: '{{ item.src }}'
        dest: '{{ item.dest }}'
      with_items:
        - { src: '/bin/bash', dest: '/bin/rbash' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/ls', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/ls' }
        - { src: '/bin/cat', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/cat' }
        - { src: '/bin/vi', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/vi' }
        - { src: '/bin/tail', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/tail' }
        - { src: '/bin/grep', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/grep' }
        - { src: '/bin/top', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/top' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/su', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/su' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/more', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/more' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/less', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/less' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/zcat', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/zcat' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/ps', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/ps' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/curl', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/curl' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/stat', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/stat' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/md5sum', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/md5sum' }
        - { src: '/usr/local/jdk/bin/jstack', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/jstack' }
        - { src: '/usr/local/jdk/bin/jstat', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/jstat' }
        - { src: '/usr/sbin/ifconfig', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/ifconfig' }
    - name: "create symbolic link for {{ limit_user }}"
      when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
      file:
        state: link
        src: '{{ item.src }}'
        dest: '{{ item.dest }}'
      with_items:
        - { src: '/bin/bash', dest: '/bin/rbash' }
        - { src: '/bin/su', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/su' }
        - { src: '/bin/ls', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/ls' }
        - { src: '/bin/cat', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/cat' }
        - { src: '/bin/more', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/more' }
        - { src: '/bin/less', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/less' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/vi', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/vi' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/tail', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/tail' }
        - { src: '/bin/grep', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/grep' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/top', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/top' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/curl', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/curl' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/stat', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/stat' }
        - { src: '/usr/bin/md5sum', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/md5sum' }
        - { src: '/bin/zcat', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/zcat' }
        - { src: '/bin/ps', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/ps' }
        - { src: '/usr/local/jdk/bin/jstack', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/jstack' }
        - { src: '/usr/local/jdk/bin/jstat', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/jstat' }
        - { src: '/sbin/ifconfig', dest: '/home/{{ limit_user }}/.bin/ifconfig' }
    - name: 'copy .bash_profile to {{ limit_user }}'
      synchronize:
        src: '{{ item }}'
        dest: /home/{{ limit_user }}
      with_items:
          - /data/control/init_hosts/limit_user/.bash_profile
          - /data/control/init_hosts/limit_user/.bashrc
    - name: 'modify {{ limit_user }} shell'
      user:
        name: '{{ limit_user }}'
        shell: /bin/rbash
```

GIF for test tab:
[rbash can't use tab to completion path in ubuntu 20.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKMqL.gif)

Comment: It appears to be sufficient to disable the *programmable* completion feature - see this (underappreciated) [so] answer: [Allow tab completion in rbash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73777881/4440445)

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work